# Does my add method do too much work?

Tags: java

I'm new to programming and I keep making the mistake of having a method do too much work. My TA gave me some advice that I should aim to make a method reusable enough that I can use it in another program without having to really modify very much. This definitely helped me approach writing methods in a better way, but I'm worried that I might have made my "add" method too meaty. Should I split it up or is it technically doing "one thing" even though it's pretty chunky?

Here's my main class (the referenced classes are just basic templates that don't do anything special aside from having getters and setters so I won't bother posting them here):

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.InputMismatchException;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 enum ClassStanding{FRESHMAN,SOPHOMORE,JUNIOR,SENIOR,UNKNOWN,MASTERS_STUDIES,PHD_STUDIES};
 enum Major{CS,CEG,EE,ISE,BME,ME,MET,UNKNOWN};
 enum StudentType{UNDERGRADUATE,GRADUATE,UNDECLARED};

public class Main {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
    int counter;
    boolean continueInput;
    int contCounter;
    do {
    do {
    System.out.print("Please enter what you want to do-ADD, REMOVE, LIST, or SAVE: ");
    switch (stdin.next().toLowerCase()) {
        case "add": add(stdin, studentList); counter = 0; break;
        case "remove": counter = 0; break;
        case "list": counter = 0; break;
        case "save": counter = 0; break;
        default: System.out.println("Improper input, please enter only ADD, REMOVE, LIST, or SAVE."); counter = 1; 
    }
    } while (counter == 1);
    do {
    System.out.print("\nDo you want to continue? Yes or no: ");
    switch (stdin.next().toLowerCase()) {
        case "yes": contCounter = 0; continueInput = true; break;
        case "no": contCounter = 0; continueInput = false; break;
        default: contCounter = 1; continueInput = false; System.out.print("\nPlease only enter 'yes' or 'no'.");
    }
    } while (contCounter == 1);
    } while (continueInput);
} // end main method

public static void add(Scanner stdin, ArrayList<Student> studentList) { // this is the one
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String uid;
    StudentType studentType;
    ClassStanding studentClassStanding;
    Major major;
    double overallGPA;
    double majorGPA;
    String majorProfessor;
    boolean thesisOption;
    System.out.print("Please enter the student's first name: ");
    String tempName = stdin.next();
    firstName = checkName(tempName);
    System.out.print("Please enter the student's last name: ");
    tempName = stdin.next();
    lastName = checkName(tempName);
    System.out.println("Please enter the student's UID in the format 'U####' or 'U#####': ");
    String tempUID = stdin.next();
    uid = checkUID(tempUID).toUpperCase();
    int count;
    do {
        System.out.print("Please enter the student's status as UNDECLARED, UNDERGRADUATE, or GRADUATE: ");
    switch (stdin.next().toUpperCase()) {
        case "UNDECLARED":
            studentType = StudentType.UNDECLARED;
            studentClassStanding = setStudentClassStanding(studentType);
            count = 0;
            Student student = new Student(firstName, lastName,
                    uid, studentType, studentClassStanding);
            studentList.add(student);
            break;
        case "UNDERGRADUATE":
            studentType = StudentType.UNDERGRADUATE;
            major = setMajor();
            studentClassStanding = setStudentClassStanding(studentType);
            System.out.println("Enter the student's overall GPA below.");
            overallGPA = setGPA();
            System.out.println("Enter the student's major GPA below.");
            majorGPA = setGPA();
            count = 0;
            UnderGraduate underGraduate = new UnderGraduate(firstName, lastName, uid, studentType,
                    studentClassStanding, major, overallGPA, majorGPA);
            studentList.add(underGraduate);
            break;
        case "GRADUATE":
            studentType = StudentType.GRADUATE;
            studentClassStanding = setStudentClassStanding(studentType);
            majorProfessor = setMajorProfessor();
            thesisOption = setThesisOption();
            count = 0;
            Graduate graduate = new Graduate(firstName, lastName, uid, studentType,
                    studentClassStanding, majorProfessor, thesisOption);
            studentList.add(graduate);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Please enter either Undeclared, Undergraduate, or Graduate only.");
            count = 1;
    }
    } while (count == 1);
}

public static String checkName(String tempName) {
    int a = 1;
    String name1;        
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        name1 = tempName; // hold the value of firstName in name1
        for (int i = 0; i < tempName.length(); i++) { // loop to check input consists of letters (is a name)
            if (!Character.isLetter(tempName.charAt(i))) { // if non-letters detected, ensure this was intentional
                System.out.println("Please ensure you've entered the correct name. Re-enter the name or enter 'continue' to proceed: ");
                tempName = scanner.nextLine();
                if (tempName.equalsIgnoreCase("continue")) { // if user enters "continue", use original input
                    a = 0;
                    tempName = name1; // pass name1 value to firstName
                    break;
                } else {
                    a = 1; // continue prompting for firstName
                }
            } else { // accept input
                a = 0;
            }
        }
    } while (a == 1); // loop to ensure proper input
    return tempName;
} // end checkName method

public static String checkUID(String tempUID) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a;
    do {
        if (tempUID.charAt(0) == 'U' || tempUID.charAt(0) == 'u') {
            if (tempUID.length() == 6 || tempUID.length() == 5) {
                a = 0;
            } else {
                a = 1;
                System.out.print("Please ensure input is in the form of U#### or U#####. Please re-enter the UID: ");
                tempUID = scan.next();
            }
        } else {
                a = 1;
                System.out.print("Please ensure input is in the form of U#### or U#####. Please re-enter the UID: ");
                tempUID = scan.next();
        }
    } while (a == 1);
    return tempUID;
} // end checkUID method

public static ClassStanding setStudentClassStanding(StudentType studentType) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count;
    ClassStanding studentTempClassStanding = null;
    do {
        if (studentType == StudentType.UNDECLARED || studentType == StudentType.UNDERGRADUATE) {
        System.out.print("Please enter the student's class standing as either Freshman, Sophomore, Junior, Senior, or Unknown: ");
        switch (scan.next().toUpperCase()) {
            case "FRESHMAN":
                studentTempClassStanding = ClassStanding.FRESHMAN;
                count = 0;
                break;
            case "SOPHOMORE":
                studentTempClassStanding = ClassStanding.SOPHOMORE;
                count = 0;
                break;
            case "JUNIOR":
                studentTempClassStanding = ClassStanding.JUNIOR;
                count = 0;
                break;
            case "SENIOR":
                studentTempClassStanding = ClassStanding.SENIOR;
                count = 0;
                break;
            case "UNKNOWN":
                studentTempClassStanding = ClassStanding.UNKNOWN;
                count = 0;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Please enter only Freshman, Sophomore, Junior, Senior, or Unknown.");
                count = 1;
        } 
        } else {
                System.out.print("Please enter the student's class standing as either 'Masters' for Masters Studies or 'PhD' for PhD Studies: ");
                switch (scan.next().toUpperCase()) {
                    case "MASTERS": studentTempClassStanding = ClassStanding.MASTERS_STUDIES; count = 0; break;
                    case "PHD": studentTempClassStanding = ClassStanding.PHD_STUDIES; count = 0; break;
                    default: System.out.println("Please enter only 'Masters' or 'PhD'.");
                count = 1;
                }
                }
    } while (count == 1);
    return studentTempClassStanding;
} // end setStudentClassStanding method

public static Major setMajor() {
    Major tempMaj = null;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int c;
    do {
        System.out.print("Please enter the student's major as either CS, CEG, EE, ISE, BME, ME, MET, or Unknown: ");
        switch (s.next().toUpperCase()) {
            case "CS":
                tempMaj = Major.CS;
                c = 0;
                break;
            case "CEG":
                tempMaj = Major.CEG;
                c = 0;
                break;
            case "EE":
                tempMaj = Major.EE;
                c = 0;
                break;
            case "ISE":
                tempMaj = Major.ISE;
                c = 0;
                break;
            case "BME":
                tempMaj = Major.BME;
                c = 0;
                break;
            case "ME":
                tempMaj = Major.ME;
                c = 0;
                break;
            case "MET":
                tempMaj = Major.MET;
                c = 0;
                break;
            case "UNKOWN":
                tempMaj = Major.UNKNOWN;
                c = 0;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Please enter only the specified values. ");
                c = 1;
        }
    } while (c == 1);
    return tempMaj;
} // end setMajor method

public static double setGPA() {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    double gpa;
    int a;
    do {
            try {
                System.out.print("Please enter the student's GPA: ");
                gpa = s.nextDouble();// read in the gpa
                if (gpa < 0.0 || gpa > 4.0) { // ensure the gpa is in the correct range
                    System.out.println("Invalid input, please enter a positive value between 0.0 and 4.0.");
                    a = 1;
                } else {
                    a = 0;
                }
            } catch (InputMismatchException ex) { //catch any exceptions, prompt for correct input
                a = 1;
                gpa = 0.0;
                System.out.println("Sorry, please enter a double value.");
                s.nextLine(); // skip the last input
            }
        } while (a == 1 || gpa < 0.0 || gpa > 4.0); //loop while gpa is negative or incorrect input is received
    return gpa;
} // end setGPA method

private static String setMajorProfessor() {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String prof;
    System.out.print("Please enter the name of the major professor: ");
    String tempName = s.nextLine();
    prof = checkName(tempName);
    return prof;
} // end setMajorProfessor method

private static boolean setThesisOption() {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean thesis = false;
    int a;
    do {
    System.out.print("Please enter 'yes' if a thesis will be written, otherwise enter 'no': ");
    switch (s.next().toUpperCase()) {
        case "YES": thesis = true; a = 0; break;
        case "NO": thesis = false; a = 0; break;
        default: System.out.println("Please enter only 'yes' or 'no'."); a = 1;
    }
    } while (a == 1);
    return thesis;
} // end setThesisOption method

}
```

The focus of this project is to have a menu of options for the user (add, list, save, sort, remove) that will allow them perform a series of operations on an arraylist they supply (through the add function). Obviously I'm not done and I'm not looking for help on my project, I'm just wondering if I made my "add" method too meaty. I tried to break it up as best I could by calling other methods to do a lot of the work in it, but I still feel like it might be too much work for the method. But then again it could be fine, I really don't know-I haven't yet gotten a feel for how much a method should really do.

Comment: Second piece of advice: no method should be more than approximately 15 lines of code.

Comment: If you are interested, you might want to look at design patterns such as [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to build things for you, and the idea of [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Comment: @CommuSoft 15 lines? I don't know how I could possibly make this method into only 15 lines. I mean, I have 10 lines for just variables. I've tried to make my other methods as short as possible, but should they really always be around 15 lines no matter what exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: For what it's worth, even professional developers make the mistake of having methods and classes do too much :/

Comment: @C.B. Thanks for the links, I would have never thought to check wiki for design guides.

Comment: @Ben: in that case you should redesign your concept. Even very complex systems have only rarely methods with more than 15 lines. Of course sometimes its argueable. But it should be an alarm that something is wrong and that you should move again to the design board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this definitely does too much.

In software design, people have introduced what they call **bad smells**, **GRASP patterns** and **design patterns** to give more scientific arguments to a discussion.

---

**Bad smells**: also called *antipatterns*. They include for instance god class (a class that does everything), seems very applicable here. These are alarms that you should *refactor* your code.

---

**GRASP patterns**: these are more or less the directions in which your code should move. Two applicable here are *controller* and *low coupeling*: split I/O and data manipulation from each other and definitely make sure that most methods don't need data provided/stored by other methods/classes.

---

**Design patterns**: these are a set of patterns one can apply to achieve the GRASP patterns. For instance you can use a *Factory* to built new instances, or use a *Chain of Responsiblity* to split a problem into small subproblems that are handled separately.

---

Some final advices by quotes:

- "Two or more, use a `for`" - E. W. Dijkstra
- "A method should in most circumstances not contain more than 15 lines" - Some of my teachers

Comment: Some good points, not sure about the last one (15 lines), especially when you need to do things like I/O or database access, easy to 10-15 lines dedicated to state management along - just saying ;) - definitely should do one thing and do it will though...

Comment: Well of course 15 is not a strict limit. If the method contains let's say 17 lines, no problem. The point is that if it contains 25 lines, you should be able to explain *why?*. And indeed I/O and database management are acceptable answers to this.

Comment: @CommuSoft Thanks, I appreciate the tips. I've tried to split up all my methods as best I can so they're as "tight" as possible. Hopefully I'll get the hang of it as I do more stuff.

Answer (score 1):

There are some rules and there are some tools to help with those rules. Basically using a static code analyzer helps to determine whether the method is too big or doing too many things. [Findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) is one of the famous static code analyzer.